# The final local variable cb may already have been assigned

Tags: java, android

I am trying to getId in the if Statement to check whether the checkboxes are set or not but I dont know how can I define the `cb` in the if Statement to get it to work.

When I declare the `cb` as local variable as commeted I am getting two Errors:

> The final local variable cb may already have been assigned
>
> Cannot invoke isChecked() on the primitive type int

```
        private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
                final CheckBox cb;
        
                final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
                for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

      //here I am getting `The final local variable cb may already have been assigned`

                    cb = new CheckBox(this);
                    cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
                    cb.setId(i);
                    ll.addView(cb);
        
                }
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
                btn.setText("submit");
                ll.addView(btn);
        
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        for (int i : items) {
                         // here I am getting `Cannot invoke isChecked() on the primitive type int
        `
                            if (cb.getId().isChecked()) {
        
                            }
                        }
        
                    }
                });
        
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared the variable as final (can't be changed once set):

```
final CheckBox cb;
```

You would either need to set the value at that point, or remove the final modifier (your loop will try to assign a value more than once).

As for the other issue:

```
if (cb.getId().isChecked())
```

When you add `.isChecked()` after `.getId()` it's a short way of saying, "call this method on the returned object of the first method.

The error is telling you that method doesn't return an object, but a primitive type (int). You need to call the second method on a Checkbox object, try something like:

```
((CheckBox)v).isChecked();
```

Or, if you already have the ID:

```
((CheckBox) findViewById(id)).isChecked();
```

Comment: You don't have to set the value at the point of declaration. But you can only assign it exactly once.

Comment: That's true - I've added clarity to make that clearer.

Comment: @Mikaveli: do I have to use the for Loop `  for (int i : items) {}` in the onClick method?

Comment: Depends - you could omit it if `cb` is the checkbox you're looking for, and just call the method on that.